# Remove template based Validation after input element removed from html in angular

Tags: angular, angular6

I wanting to do validation based on input flag, But unfortunately it fails my validation. If i use template validation it fails or if i use Form Validation it works. But for satisfying my requirement i need to use template based validation.

Below is code and screen shot

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
        <h1>Angular Sample </h1>
        <form [formGroup]="countryForm">
        <input type="checkbox"
                   formControlName="city" /> Is Other City 
        <ng-container *ngIf='countryForm.value.city'>
        <hr />
        <label>City : </label>
        <input 
                   required='true'
                   placeholder="Enter city Name"
                   formControlName="cityName" />
        </ng-container>
        <hr />
        <button [disabled]="countryForm.invalid">Submit</button>
        </form>
`
})
export class AppComponent {

  countryForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    city: new FormControl(),
    cityName: new FormControl(),
  });
  constructor() { }
}
```

[image: Step 001]

[image: Step 002]

[image: Step 003]

[image: Step 004]

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Valid Flag is not updating after disappear city Name from UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable/disable a form control by using Instantiate a new FormControl with the disabled property set to true. `FormControl({value: '', disabled: true})`

Then Using control.disable() or control.enable() method to enable or disable, method as per your need.

**app.component.ts**

```
constructor() {
    this.countryForm = new FormGroup({
      city: new FormControl(),
      cityName: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: false }),
    });


    this.countryForm.get('city').valueChanges.subscribe(v => {
      v ? this.countryForm.get('cityName').enable() : this.countryForm.get('cityName').disable();
    })
  }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/stack-overflowexample